# Can't access to parent javascript in browsers tablets (except Firefox) from iframe

Tags: javascript, android, tablet

I have an iframe on a page and I want to access to a function of parent page from this iframe.
In PC browsers works well using this:

```
parent.function()
```

The problem is in tablet browsers, when I try to access to the function, it returns 'undefined' and it doesn't find the parent, it's like not exist. But this problem not happen in Firefox browser for Android, it's the only browser that works well in tablets.

PD: both pages (parent and iframe) are in the same domain.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the browser is html5 try use html5 comunication method: postMessage. postMesseage allows cross-origin comunication.

```
//parent code
window.addEventListener("message",function(msg){
    msg.data;
    //... do something
}, false);

//iframe code
parent.postMessage("hi daddy");
```

using JSON.parse(...) and JSON.stringify(...) you can send objects like:

```
{
    command: "methodName",
    arguments:[100, 200, "my string"]
}
```

parent window should interpret the command sent by the iframe. Thus you have a small API implementation allowed for iframes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage